# Managing encoding with JSONResponse

Tags: python, json, django, character-encoding, serialization

My problem concerns an API in Django. I have severals objects to serialize, this works well. The problem is that accents are not correctly encoded, for example :

```
L'\u00c9tranger #instead of L'étranger
```

To display that I use serializer this way :

```
serializer = MyClassSerializer(MyObjects, many=True)
return JSONResponse(serializer.data)
```

My `JSONResponse` class extends from `HttpResponse` :

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
(...)
class JSONResponse(HttpResponse):
    """
    An HttpResponse that renders its content into JSON.
    """
    def __init__(self, data, **kwargs):
        content = JSONRenderer().render(data)
        kwargs['content_type'] = 'application/json'
        super(JSONResponse, self).__init__(content, **kwargs)
```

By searching in documentation I read about an optional parameter in `JSONResponse` : `JSONencoder` but the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/request-response/#changing-the-default-json-encoder) is poor about this.

Thank you for reading.

EDIT:

When I do :

> > > print h.request("http://myu.rl/s/Camus%2BAlbert/")

I still have :

```
"titre": "L\'\\u00c9tranger"
```

Here is my livre model :

```
class Livre(models.Model):
    auteur = models.ForeignKey(Auteur)
    titre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    genre = models.ForeignKey(Genre)
    publish_date = models.DateField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('auteur','titre', 'publish_date'),)
```

But it is not stored in database I just use it as a wrapper in that case.

May I had that when I execute directly the script that fill up the Livre class before giving it to the real API service (the one who serialize and make json), I have this :

```
>>>>python book_search.py -s "Albert Camus"
L'Étranger
```

The main block just call : `GoogleBook.search(search_keywords)`

Comment: It is Unicode, what is wrong? If you will render this on UI, or Mobile devices they will regognize this correctly.

Comment: I showed you my browser output and what is wrong is the fact that accents are not well displayed. I really don't understand you're comment wolendranh.

Comment: @Totem json strings are supposed to be Unicode strings, and what you show above is the *representation* of the unicode string for "L'Étranger". Try `print u"L'\u00c9tranger` in your Python shell... Now you say "I showed you my browser output", but you don't explain which browser nor how you get this output - is this the browser's attempt at rendering the raw json content or this is from some browser-side javascript doing a request and updating the dom with the json data ? Also, you don't post anything about your model, custom serializer etc... Is at least your data OK in the DB itself ???

Comment: Thank you Bruno for your explanation, I understand now. I was displaying the raw JSON output in my browser. 

This is not solved, but I gave you more details in my updated post.